# How does one implement scroll hijacking (scrolljacking) in the browser (react or vanilla js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, scroll

I've been trying to implement something like what Typeform does (Example https://www.typeform.com/templates/t/online-quote-form/?preview=template) where the user can't scroll the page, and instead any scroll trigger just advances to the next question.

So far I've figured out that it's insufficient to add a handler to the scroll event. It seems like I need to add handlers to wheel, keydown, swipe, and maybe other things, to implement the different scrolling behavior.

But I can't seem to work out all of the kinks. In particular, a wheel scroll will have the expected behavior and then continue scrolling, and I can't seem to cancel that behavior.

(I'm aware that this is a UX antipattern; I'm doing it anyway.)

At the moment I don't have a reasonable code sample but I'll add one if nobody has a solution offhand.

Comment: Ok so the problem I was having was that in Chrome, wheel events are passive by default, so I had to add `passive: false` to the event handler. I'll clean this up and post an answer to this when I get a chance.